TP Link AC600 does not list any networks
I have purchased a tp link AC600 usb wifi adapter.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 on a macbook, therefore my kernel is 6.6.62-1-t2-noble
I have installed the drivers according to these instructions
I think the drivers' installation went well, since as you can see in the screenshot the device is displayed in the gnome interface.
However, in contrast to the built-in device (Broadcom) it does not list any networks.
Any suggestions?

